# Mongoose - Query Mongo Array of Objects, match any Object in search Array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongo schema with two arrays of objects that looks like:

```
genre: {Type: [Object]},
type: {Type: [Object]}

Example Document Data:
genre: [
{name: "scifi", selected: true}, 
{name: "fantasy", selected: false,
{name: "western", selected: true}, 
],
type: [
{name: "module", selected: true},
{name: "rulebook", selected: true},
{name: "artwork", selected: false},
]
```

How would I execute a query that takes in an array of genres/types and returns any documents that match?

```
findGenres = [
    {name: "scifi", selected: true}, 
    {name: "western", selected: true}, 
]
findTypes = [
    {name: "rulebook", selected: true}
]
```

So when I search this would return only the rulebooks marked scifi, or western.

Answer (score 0):

Let's cut the query into half for better explanation.

**PART 1 (EDITED)**

for checking name and selected of a single object in `genre` you can use this query to find a single item in an array:

`model.find('genre': {"$elemMatch": {name: "scifi", selected: true} })`

> you can do the same for `type`

#### **PART 2**

since we have different values to search for you can use `$in` to find all matches for different values.

```
model.find({
    "$or": [
        {'genre': {"$elemMatch": {name: "scifi", selected: true} }},
        {'type': {"$elemMatch": {name: "rulebook", selected: true} }}
     ]
)}
```

#### **PART 3**

Now all you have to do is map `findGenres` and `findTypes` into the same array in part 1 and put in to part 2 and it's done.

hope it helps ;)

Comment: In part 1, wouldn't you need to use `$elemMatch` like this: `genre: { $elemMatch: { name: "scifi", selected: true } }` otherwise, the query will match with any document which has at least one element in the array where the `name` is "scifi" and at least one element where the `selected` attribute is `true`. (It doesn't need to be the same element which is my concern here).

Comment: so, you want the result to have both `name` and `selected` match your query, right?

Comment: Im not the same Alex who has asked the question, but I would assume that Alex wants to do that, yes.